# App size increase due to realm android

Tags: android, realm

I am adding some data into realm database after every 15 sec through a service.

After a whole night, the size of app become 350mb due to realm, its confirm..

But if i delete that data from realm, after some condition, the data deleted but the size of app still shown 350mb.

The question is why the app size is not shrinking now.

Comment: Could you show some code how you deleted the realm data?

Answer (score 2):

Realm currently doesn't automatically reclaim the space used by your database, but it will be reused if you later add data again.

If you wish to free the disk space you can use `Realm.compactRealm()`: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#compactRealm-io.realm.RealmConfiguration-

However, a file size of 350 MB sounds like quite a lot. Are you really inserting that much data?

Comment: yes, data is adding after every 15 sec..  over a whole night

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot compact an open Realm
            at io.realm.BaseRealm.compactRealm(BaseRealm.java:585)
            at io.realm.Realm.compactRealm(Realm.java:1200)
            at com.megacabs.app.driver.commons.DBDeleteRow.deleteDBWithObjectId(DBDeleteRow.java:47)
            at com.megacabs.app.driver.commons.DBDeleteRow.run(DBDeleteRow.java:22)     It showing me this error always

Comment: Yes, you need to close the Realm before you can compact it.

Comment: still showing me this error ever after using it after realm.close.

Comment: You need to close EVERY realm instance to that given realm configuration on EVERY thread.

Comment: I am saving lat lng in realm at every 5 sec, so it's been difficult for me to check whether realm instance close or not  while executing compactRealm(config).... how can i solve it............

Answer (score 0):

```
    Realm realm = null;
    RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(MyApplication.appInstance().getApplicationContext())
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .build();
    try {
        realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    RealmResults<MqttLocationModel> result2 = realm.where(MqttLocationModel.class).equalTo("uid", objectId).findAll();
    Log.e("Delted  object id",""+objectId);
    Log.e("Delted DB Size",""+result2.size());
    realm.beginTransaction();
    result2.clear();
    realm.commitTransaction();

    RealmResults<MqttLocationModel> result3 = realm.where(MqttLocationModel.class).equalTo("uid", objectId).findAll();
    Log.e("Delted final DB Size",""+result3.size());

    realm.close();

    realm.compactRealm(config);
```

Comment: E/UncaughtException﹕ java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot compact an open Realm
            at io.realm.BaseRealm.compactRealm(BaseRealm.java:585)
            at io.realm.Realm.compactRealm(Realm.java:1200)
            at com.megacabs.app.driver.commons.DBDeleteRow.deleteDBWithObjectId(DBDeleteRow.java:47)
            at com.megacabs.app.driver.commons.DBDeleteRow.run(DBDeleteRow.java:22)

Answer (score 0):

Your service executes on a background thread, so you probably have a single realm open on a BACKGROUND THREAD for the whole duration of the sync procedure, thus creating multiple versions of the Realm.

If this is true, you should either close and reopen the Realm after a transaction, or use `waitForChange ()`.

Comment: I am saving lat lng in realm at every 5 sec, so it's been difficult for me to check whether realm instance close or not  while executing compactRealm(config).... how can i solve it............

Comment: I never thought I'd say this, but I think you should consider saving these values to the Realm on the UI thread.