# Realm large db size due to frequent updates

Tags: android, realm

I have a thread running every second that updates Realm database fields every second. While the data being updated is tiny, I've found out that updates still increase the database filesize until you explicitly clean it with `Realm.compressRealm()` so within an hour or two the db size is 50MB+ and will easily bloat up to 750MB+ in a short period as well.

I am closing the Realm with `realm.close()` in the Activity `onStop()` and also closing the new Realm instance I create in the timer thread:

```
public void checkDealersTimer() {
    RealmResults<Dealers> dealersLookup = realm.where(Dealers.class).equalTo("thedealers","thedealers").findAll();
    dlr = dealersLookup.get(0);

    if (dlr.getPerSecond() != 0.00) {
        if (dealerTimer == null) {
            dealerTimer = new Timer();
            dealerTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Realm drealm;
                    drealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

                    RealmResults<Dealers> dealersLookup = drealm.where(Dealers.class).equalTo("thedealers","thedealers").findAll();
                    dlr = dealersLookup.get(0);

                    drealm.beginTransaction();
                    dlr.setEarnings(dlr.getEarnings()+dlr.getPerSecond());
                    drealm.commitTransaction();
                    drealm.close();
                }
            }, 0, 1000);

        }
    }
}
```

This timer is the only place I use Realm outside of the UI thread, and the only place I am making updates so frequent, so I am assuming the "leak" is coming from here though I cannot be sure. The filesize creeps up wether the app is visible or not, but only when it is running.

Here's another user with a similar issue:
[App size increase due to realm android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37453353/app-size-increase-due-to-realm-android)

If that is believed to be the solution, I cannot find the correct way to call `Realm.compressRealm()` since the db is supposed to be updating every second when you're using it, and I can only close the Realm `onDestroy()` not `onStop()` (and `Realm.compressRealm()` requires you to close all Realms)

I appreciate any input, thank you!

Comment: If you do close the Realm instance after use (especially those in the background non-looper thread because of they won't be updated and lock to a special version of data forever), it is normally no need to call `compactRealm()` and the file size won't be too big. So take a look of @oddmeter 's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had an issue where my realm file size was increasing at an alarming rate, and it was an issue of not calling `close()` when the app closed unexpectedly during development. As such my database file (only had about 1k items in it) was at 10MB. Properly closing out my realm instance solved the problem and reduced my database file size to ~300KB. Really, it's worth checking your entire codebase to make sure you're actually closing out **all** realm instances. It's annoying, but way better than having users complain about running out of storage ;)

Based on your example above, I'd recommend also using the executeTransaction method (instead of beginning/committing transactions) provided by realm:

```
drealm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        dlr.setEarnings(dlr.getEarnings() + dlr.getPerSecond());
    }
});

drealm.close();
```

Comment: In fact, put it in finally

Comment: I've heard conflicting info about `realm.close()` - some have said to use that method everytime you open a new instance, whereas others have said just having one `realm.close()` in `onDestroy()` is enough. I have one god activity, many dialogfragments, adapters etc all opening new instances. `realm.close()` should be added to those fragments, adapters etc as well? Thank you

Comment: @zngb I'm still new to realm and have my realm connections open only as long as I need them. I had one problem area where my app was crashing during development, and once I included the `realm.close()` there, my file size issues were gone. The documentation makes it sound as though the file size grows with each transaction that's open, so I interpreted that to mean that I should close connections as quickly as possible to avoid large files.